# Can I register in Google cloud and Amazon cloud without credit card for free trial?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-cloudtrail

I want to register on the site for free trial, but as I have seen, they want from me a credit card, unfortunately I do not have a credit card (because the conditions of my country to obtain it are impossible), is there another way to register without credit card ?

Answer (score 4):

1. So far as I know You can get a prepaid virtual credit card and register for AWS cloud
2. But for the Google cloud you will need a original credit card. These prepaid credit cards wont work

Answer (score 1):

Just in case: if you are affiliated with a public research institute, you can indeed register without a credit card. See section 2.4 in of the [AWS Research Cloud Program](https://aws.amazon.com/government-education/research-and-technical-computing/research-cloud-program/) handbook version 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to sign up without a credit card. One possibility would be to find an American or citizen of the UK willing to open the account on your behalf with their own card, maybe pay them with bitcoin or another digital currency.

Comment: Thats not something you want people to do..